# How to remove blank line in Sakura editor?

Tags: text-editor

I need to prepare test data having around 10K lines with many blank lines, same has to be removed. Earlier I was using editplus (Text editor) and could able to solve very easily by using Find (Find text: "\n\n" Regular expression) and Replace (empty) option.

Here in this project I am using Sakura editor and tried the below option to remove blank lines but its not working.

[image]
Need to remove line 6 and 7.

**Find text**

- \n\n
- \r\n\r\n
- [\r\n]+[\r\n]

More information about using of regular expression in sakura editor
[Click here](http://wikiwiki.jp/wakura/?sakura%2Fen%2FRegular%20Expression%20can%20be%20Used)

PS: I have some restriction in my current project to download and install any other software/tools.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution. Like to share with others. 
In sakura editor, we can remove the empty lines by using find and replace option.

Find `^\r\n` 【Option:Regular expression】 and replace

**Explanation**

```
^ Beginning of the line
\r carriage-return character
\n newline (line feed) character
```